# FLINK Streaming from KAFKA KRB5 Kerberos Issue

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to stream data from flink kafkaconsumer using:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html

Here my KAFKA is Kerberos secured and SSL enabled.

I am running my Flink streaming in yarn-cluster on EMR 5.31.

I am getting following error related to REALM KRB5.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException:
Failed to create SaslClient with mechanism GSSAPI

Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failure to initialize
security context [Caused by GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism
level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)]
```

I passed KRB5 from yaml conf file like:

```
env.java.opts.jobmanager: -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/path/krb5.conf
env.java.opts.taskmanager: -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/path/krb5.conf
```

How can I resolve this? Is there another way to pass KRB5?

Answer (score 2):

Had shipped the directory conf/ using --yarn-ship. This conf folder has krb5.conf in it

and then finally when I passed it from flink-conf.yaml with relative path. Like below it worked:

> env.java.opts.jobmanager: -Djava.security.krb5.conf=./conf/krb5.conf
> env.java.opts.taskmanager: -Djava.security.krb5.conf=./conf/krb5.conf
> env.java.opts: -Djava.security.krb5.conf=./conf/krb5.conf

other options with -yD didn't work for me.